# need help with a RegEX to match comments with no unicode chrarchters there

Tags: regular-expression

so here is my example

```
#match
     #match
 #match
foobar#not-matched
```

the regex I was using was `\s?\#` but this ended up matching `$#` in my bash script which I don't want it to do

that or a regex which matches everything *but* a comment so if i input a string
`command#comment` it would return with just `command`

Comment: Your question is too unclear. Your example makes it sound as if you *do* want to match the first line, but the first line is precisely what matches the regex '$#` which you say you *don't* want to match. The example also makes it seem as if you don't want to match the last line, but the last sentence makes it sound as if you want a replacement on lines like that. Are you filtering lines, or changing them? What command are you using (`sed`,`grep`,etc.) and what are you trying to do? Give an example input and desired output.

Comment: Note that if you're processing shell-script source code, `command#comment` **is** a command (or a single word) and contains no comment, because a hash mark in the middle of a word is considered a word character, not a comment marker. A regular-expression answer can match those cases as you asked, but that may not do what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `/^\s?\#/gm`

the `^` character specifies only the start of the string.

the `m` at the end is multi-line, allowing it to match more than one line.
the `g` at the end is global, allowing it to match more than one match.

if you are just checking line by line, you only need `^\s\#`

Comment: This seems to assume particular tools not included in the question nor named in this answer.

Comment: the OP asked me on discord first, so I just put that answer here